# Hatching on filtered region of raster layer

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld, netcdf

I've created RasterSymbolizer-based styles (colour ramps )for a bunch of trend maps layers (from NetCDFs) in GeoServer, and I serve them over WMS. I also have matching p-value raster layers, and I'd like to fill the parts of those layers with a hatching pattern, rather than a solid fill (because I want to overlay the statistical significance on the trend layer as a layer group).

I understand that hatching fill is not available with the
RasterSymbolizer, but it *is* doable with a PolygonSymbolizer. According to
the YSLD reference
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/symbolizers/index.html;,
the latter can actually be applied to a raster. Sure enough, when I create
a PolygonSymbolizer style and preview the p-value, I get a big, green
square the size of the map.

But if I try to add a Filter, things stop working. The style validates, btu the Layer Preview no longer works properly. Here's what I'm trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd";
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"; xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc";
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; xmlns:xsi="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">;

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Statistically significant trend (p lt 0.05)</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Statistically significant trend (p lt 0.05)</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Stat. sig. (p &lt; 0.05)</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>quantity</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#D3FFD3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#6DB26D</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

One problem could be the `PropertyName` value: I'm not sure whether to just
use 'quantity', or the band name (which is 'pvalue' for all of the layers I
want to use this style with) or the layer name (which varies). None of these work. Or maybe the Filter is incompatible with raster layers (even when they're using `PolygonSymbolizer`)? I'm not sure.

If someone can help me with this (or an alternate way to get hatch fills over parts of a raster layer), that'd be fantastic :)

Answer (score 1):

A polygon symbolizer applied on a raster does just that, takes the bbox of the raster and treats it as a polygon. No filtering is possible.

If you want to treat your raster as set of filterable polygons, make it into polygons using a rendering transformation instead, see a SLD example here:

https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/rendering_tx.html#contour-extraction-styled-as-polygons

Comment: Ah, I wondered if that might be the case. Thanks—I'll give the rendering transformation a go in a couple of days!

Comment: I haven't quite been able to get there yet—I'm trying to follow the PolygonExtraction example with a single range of `[0;0.05]`, but the error I'm getting in the logs when I try to request the layer is: `Caused by: java.security.InvalidParameterException: Could not convert the value [0;0.05] into the expected type class org.jaitools.numeric.Range for parameter ranges`. I'm wondering if I need to escape something here?